# Can't load Ubuntu 7.10 with Displayport

Tags: boot, nvidia, 17.10, hdmi, displayport

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 fresh. I can boot into it just fine with HDMI on my monitor. I have an LG 27UD69P. I'm running a DisplayPort from my 1050ti. I can use the HDMI just fine but cant boot in with DP. I see the bootloader but instead of loading the login screen, its just black and purple static. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use the proprietary drivers?

Comment: I just tried to install the Nvidia drivers, it tells me it can't be installed due to Nouveau

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a huge headache and serious digging with a lot of trial and error, I go it to boot with the DP.

It took about 4 times but finally got Nouveau uninstalled and got Nvidia drivers installed using [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) method.

It takes a little longer to boot, but at least I'm not constantly messing with different wires.

Comment: Since the content linked to can disappear, please add the relevant details into your answer here.

Comment: Also set this as the solution.